# refactor - remove CRPT

Tags: c++11, templates, refactoring

I have custom List class like this:

```
template<class T>
struct iList{
    constexpr bool empty() const{
        return static_cast<const T *>(this)->size() == 0;
    }

    // several methods like empty(), some are non const.
};

// there are several classes like this one with different implementations
struct MyList : iList<MyList>{
    constexpr unsigned size() const{
        return 5;
    }
};

int main(){
    constexpr MyList list;
    static_assert( ! list.empty() );
}
```

code is `constexpr` and simplified so I can use `static_assert`.

I want to get rid of CRTP pattern, because templates become way too ugly. However I do not want to use virtual functions.

One way I am thinking is following:

```
struct iList2{
protected:
    template<class LIST>
    constexpr static bool empty_(const LIST &list){
        return list.size() == 0;
    }
};

struct MyList2 : iList2{
    constexpr unsigned size() const{
        return 5;
    }

    constexpr bool empty() const{
        return empty_(*this);
    }
};

int main(){
    constexpr MyList2 list2;
    static_assert( ! list2.empty() );
}
```

In this case I need to call `empty_` static member function in each list.

Another way is to use mixin, e.g. to inherit `MyList` and add empty() method. If I do this as templated class, I can even make typedef. However I do not like this approach as well.

Is there any possibility I am missing?

Comment: Just make `empty` a method of `MyList`, and drop `iList` entirely. It doesn't appear to serve any purpose.

Comment: is not just empty, there are several methods like empty, some are even non const

Comment: Move all of them to `MyList`, and drop `iList` entirely.

Comment: I have 5-6 classes like MyList

Comment: So you want a mixin class that would implement boilerplate methods in terms of non-boilerplate business logic ones. CRTP is perhaps the best way to do that. What's wrong with it?

Comment: some of the classes are decorators or list that contains two lists and thing are similar to this https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4/blob/master/hm4/flushlist.h things soon my get out of hand :)